# How to Syntax OrderBy whit value in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to add a by order with value in eloquent, how can I do it?

example

Order By
c.id = 23 DESC

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ku5rF.png)

Comment: can't you use where?

Comment: Have you tried `orderBy('c.id', 'desc`)` or `orderByDesc('c.id')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a joined table if yes show model and controller?

if it not joined table then try this:

->orderBy('c.id','DESC'), or ->orderByCId('DESC') or ->orderByDesc('c.id')